# RF-transceiver for real-time video streaming?

Tags: radio-control

I'm working on an RC-controlled model aircraft. One of the features I'd like to implement is real-time video streaming from the drone's camera. Distance is going to be a few dozen, or better hundred meters.

Obviously, communication link bandwidth is a weak chain here.

How should I approach it? Are there communication protocols and hardware modules I could make use of?

Answer (score 0):

Drones typically use 5.8Ghz for FPV, you can pick up cameras, transmitters and receivers quite cheaply that are already integrated. Some newer models have OTG UVC support to plug directly into a smartphone.

https://www.banggood.com/Eachine-TX02-Super-Mini-AIO-5_8G-40CH-200mW-VTX-600TVL-14-Cmos-FPV-Camera-p-1088368.html?rmmds=search

https://www.banggood.com/Eachine-ROTG01-UVC-OTG-5_8G-150CH-Full-Channel-FPV-Receiver-For-Android-Mobile-Phone-Smartphone-p-1147692.html?rmmds=detail-top-buytogether-auto&ID=224